# What does a i2c_new_dummy do?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am working on an mfd driver. There is a single i2c bus, shared by four i2c client devices (on s single IC). The `i2c_new_dummy` API is used when attaching an adapter to each of the clients.

Why is it necessary to have a different adapter logic for different clients? How does an mfd device actually work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As we know, the `I2C` bus will have 127 clients from the spec definition; a `7bit` *address* with  `1bit` for *read/write*.

The first byte will be the `I2C` device *address*, and the device matching this address, will pull down the `ACK` bit. Next follows the **data**, most of the time this will be the address of a register.

So, if you have four `I2C` clients, you will get four devices and four client handles, even if they are contained in the **SOC**.

But sometimes you don't need so much.

Another case is on current **SOC**, one chip (like tps65910) will have lots of function, include turning on voltage, **CODEC**, and so on. Every driver will use `I2C` to set the register. You can not request one handle for one driver so this is why it call `i2c_new_dummy`.

Comments from kernel *i2c-core.c*,

```
/**
 * i2c_new_dummy - return a new i2c device bound to a dummy driver
 * @adapter: the adapter managing the device
 * @address: seven bit address to be used
 * Context: can sleep
 *
 * This returns an I2C client bound to the "dummy" driver, intended for use
 * with devices that consume multiple addresses.  Examples of such chips
 * include various EEPROMS (like 24c04 and 24c08 models).
 *
 * These dummy devices have two main uses.  First, most I2C and SMBus calls
 * except i2c_transfer() need a client handle; the dummy will be that handle.
 * And second, this prevents the specified address from being bound to a
 * different driver.
 *
 * This returns the new i2c client, which should be saved for later use with
 * i2c_unregister_device(); or NULL to indicate an error.
 */
```